# .htaccess: RewriteRule problem

Tags: regex, .htaccess

i need to much the sentense, if it doesn't contain some words
i wrote it like this

```
^([^news|home|rules|contacts|month_films|archive|ratings])$
```

but it doesn't work. 
could you tell me why? thanks

Comment: Everything about that expression is so wrong to the point that I'm not sure what you're even trying to do with it. Can you explain in plain English what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Welbog i just need to find the sentense, if it doesn't contain none of those words(the problem is in it).
so, whn i write ^([^news|home|rules|contacts|month_films|archive|ratings])$ is it true?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, put a ! in front of the regular expression and use a RewriteCond:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(news|home|rules|contacts|month_films|archive|ratings)
 RewriteRule <whatever it is you want to do>
```

Comment: @Kinopiko it is interesting! but i don't know about RewriteCond:(
what is {REQUEST_URI}?

Comment: Please refer to the Apache documentation.

Answer (score 0):

try this (without []):

```
 ^(news|home|rules|contacts|month_films|archive|ratings)$
```

Comment: but that would exactly match "news" for example - I think he wants to match everything *except* "news", etc.